# link redirection in mailgun

Tags: email, redirect, mailgun, email-templates

we are using mailgun send mails in our project.

but there is a small issue with a one functionality which is password reset

I attach a password reset url  (to a button) with the token to a mail template, and this is the template end users are receiving for password reset.

i'll attach like a url  like below

- https://{domain}/forget-password/{token}

But the mail template that receiving is not the same one i'm sending :) 
url is changed into something below

- http://email.{domain}/c/{some-other-token}

but when the link that you are sending is clicked, is redirected to the url i'm originally attached in the first place.

I'll briefly explain the behavior again for the further calification

1) lets assume this is the url i'm attaching to the mail template.

```
 - https://{domain}/forget-password/{token}
```

2) but end users are receiving a url like below

```
 - https://email.{domain}/c/{some-other-token}
```

3) but when its clicked (2nd one) redirected to the original url that i'm attaching (1st one)

```
 - https://{domain}/forget-password/{token}
```

but the real problems is this redirecting is only happening on some browsers like Firefox and IE but its not working on chrome. (redirecting is not working on chrome) so it displays a 404 message after some time and end users cannot see the password reset page :/ 
can any one explain this behavior? and can any one explain why this is not working on chrome and can you explain me a method to solve this if it can solve it in my side ? (if possible) :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. I think this cause because of DNS cache and if you flush the DNS cache this solves temporally but if you don't want link click tracking using below URL

https://app.mailgun.com/app/sending/domains/PUT_YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE/settings

Comment: Your link doesn't work. its redirecting to login page. If this is the correct answer then add important information from the link to this answer please.

Comment: You just need to replace the "PUT_YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE" with your domain